# function .navigateTo() don't always work on Testcafe

Tags: navigation, automated-tests, localhost, e2e-testing, testcafe

Some of the URLs are not loading when running testcafe. For example when I try to redirect to the localhost, it is not loading and going straight to the next step.

```
await t.navigateTo('localhost:8080')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because testcafe doesn't support navigateTo without a protocol, so you need to add https:// or http:// before the url. In this case when I changed to:

```
await t.navigateTo('http://localhost:8080')
```

It has worked.

Comment: The [navigateTo](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html) action accepts an absolute or relative URL. An absolute URL must contain a scheme (protocol), which specifies how the resource is to be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason not to use a relative path here? This should work.

```
await t.navigateTo('/')
```